# Can someone please guide me how to filter the contents from Jface TreeViewer?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, treeviewer

I am new in creating TreeViewer.
I am creating a treeviewer using a HashMap `Map<String, List<String>> typeDefsTreeMap = new HashMap<>()`

Now I want to filter the contents of TreeViewer.
Can someone help me in filtering the contents of TreeViewer?

I tried to use ViewerFilter like below

```
treeViewer.addFilter(new ViewerFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean select(Viewer viewer, Object parentElement, Object element) {
       if (element.toString().toLowerCase()
                                       .contains(searchFilterText.getText().toLowerCase())) {
          return element instanceof String;
        }
    return element instanceof String;
    }
});
```

But at the end I need to put a selection on that element which is filtered,
as I do not want to hide anything with filter, I just want to select the first element which has filtered text.

How can I do that in treeviewer?

Comment: See [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html#filtering-data)

Comment: Or  [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JFaceSnippets#Snippet_041_-_Table_Viewer_Alternating_Colors_and_Viewer_Filters)